# How works ANeuralNetworksMemory_createFromFd?

Tags: android, c++, c, tensorflow-lite, nnapi

In Android Neural Network API docs says: Creates a shared memory object from a file descriptor.

But I can't find any place that specifies how is the format of this file, on TFL source code:

allocation.cc:

```
MMAPAllocation::MMAPAllocation(const char* filename,
                               ErrorReporter* error_reporter)
    : Allocation(error_reporter), mmapped_buffer_(MAP_FAILED) {
  mmap_fd_ = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
  if (mmap_fd_ == -1) {
    error_reporter_->Report("Could not open '%s'.", filename);
    return;
  }
  struct stat sb;
  fstat(mmap_fd_, &sb);
  buffer_size_bytes_ = sb.st_size;
  mmapped_buffer_ =
      mmap(nullptr, buffer_size_bytes_, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, mmap_fd_, 0);
  if (mmapped_buffer_ == MAP_FAILED) {
    error_reporter_->Report("Mmap of '%s' failed.", filename);
    return;
  }
}
```

nnapi_delegate.cc

```
NNAPIAllocation::NNAPIAllocation(const char* filename,
                                 ErrorReporter* error_reporter)
    : MMAPAllocation(filename, error_reporter) {
  if (mmapped_buffer_ != MAP_FAILED)
    CHECK_NN(ANeuralNetworksMemory_createFromFd(buffer_size_bytes_, PROT_READ,
                                                mmap_fd_, 0, &handle_));
}
```

It means, TFL opens the file, and give this file to NNAPI. What I need is what is the format of this file that store the tensors, is it a flatbuffers file like TFL format?

Edit:
This is a sample from NNAPI doc:

```
ANeuralNetworksMemory* mem1 = NULL;
int fd = open("training_data", O_RDONLY);
ANeuralNetworksMemory_createFromFd(file_size, PROT_READ, fd, 0, &mem1);
```

This file `training_data`, how must its content be structured to NNAPI understand?

Comment: ANeuralNetworksMemory_createFromFd doesn't care what format your file is.

Comment: So, how this function fill the tensors parameters?

Comment: It doesn't. It creates a memory object from a file descriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANeuralNetworksMemory_createFromFd(file_size, PROT_READ, **fd**, 0, &**mem1**) - This API maps the model file in to ANeuralNetworksMemory.

The mapped address is stored in **mem1** (pass by reference!)

Further, trained values that are stored in **mem1** (ANeuralNetworksMemory object) is read by pointing to the appropriate offset value and copied in to the tensors of NeuralNetwork model.

```
 ANeuralNetworksModel_setOperandValueFromMemory(model_, tensor0, mem1, offset, size);
 ANeuralNetworksModel_setOperandValueFromMemory(model_, tensor1, mem1, offset+size, size);
```

- tensor0 -  pointing at **offset**
- tensor1 -  pointing at **offset+size**

Answer (score 1):

The loading of the model file and the parsing of it are done separately. This makes it easier to mix-and-match between different memory models and different file formats. It also makes it possible to use these building blocks for other functions, like loading inputs from a file.

ANeuralNetworksMemory_createFromFd() is just used to load the model file into memory.

FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile() gets an allocation (memory block) that represents the model. This is where ANeuralNetworksMemory_createFromFd() gets called. Then it news up a FlatBufferModel object. This calls tflite::GetModel() which is in the schema subdirectory. The schema subdirectory deserializes the flat-buffer-model from the .tflite model loaded into memory.

When NNAPIDelegate::Invoke() is called, the schema Model object is used to build the model in the Android-NN layer using calls like ANeuralNetworksModel_addOperand().